# Prohibit requesting of transation isolatoin level below specified one in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level

Is there a way to prohibit usage of isolaton levels below specified one in Postgres? I want isolation level of all transactions in DB to be a REPEATABLE READ at least, and raise error if user tries to set READ COMMITED, for example.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without hacking the server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to change the code of `check_transaction_isolation()` in `src/backend/commands/variable.c` to return `false` if `newXactIsoLevel < XACT_REPEATABLE_READ`.